# Blender quits after pressing the P key

Tags: python, linux

I'm using blender with a **Raspberry Pi 3 model B**. When I use the text editor and run the script, it show that my program runs normally in the terminal. But, when I add the `bge` library and try to run the program by pressing the ***P*** key, blender quits.

If I run the text editor as a script it show me an error telling me that `the bge not a library in Python`, so the only way to run the project is by pressing ***P*** key.

At first, when I run blender in terminal it show me this message:
[image]

But, after pressing ***P*** key in blender the program quit and the terminal show me this message: 
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is related but is your pi able to run blender? I have one too and though it's great it's not very powerful.

Comment: so you think the problem in the raspberry pi not in the system or the program ??

Comment: Could well be though have you checked your bash commands or tried a different terminal? Also is it possible to map the command to a different key and tried that?

Comment: all keys work perfectly just when i put the p key the program stop and quit no just the p key also when i start the game engine by clicking the start button but what you mean about "have you checked your bash commands or tried a different terminal? "

Comment: Was just wondering if the issue was in the command line. If you're on Linux then chances are you're using bash is all.

Comment: Why are you using sudo to start blender? You do know that running GUI tools as root that don't require it is not recommended, furthermore that are not designed to do that will cause all kinds of problems. There are tools that need root privileges, but Blender is not one of them.